# Problem with HTTP traffic being 'hijacked' by firewall

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, ip, email, netgear

I'm experiencing a major head-ache at the moment with our company firewall, we're currently changing ISPs (new lease line and new block of static IPs) and I'm setting up firewall rules (we're using a [NETGEAR ProSafe VPN Firewall FVX538)](http://www.netgear.com/business/products/security/wired-VPN-firewalls/FVX538.aspx).

The firewall is visible internally on `1.1.1.2` (all IPs for example only) and we can configure it through the web admin on ports 80 and 443. All traffic *from* our building goes out on `123.123.123.102`, but when you go to the `123.123.123.102` IP (from within or outside the network), the firewall admin page is shown. This isn't really what we want!

I've tried adding firewall rules for HTTP traffic on `123.123.123.102` to be routed to one of our web servers at `1.1.1.9`, but when I add this rule, requests to `123.123.123.102` just hang. If I change my rule to `123.123.123.103`, it works fine but the NETGEAR admin's still visible on `123.123.123.102` - problem not solved.

The *real* problem is that this means we can't point our domain `example.com` to `123.123.123.102`, because the NETGEAR admin would show rather than our site, but we *need* this domain to resolve to `123.123.123.102` because all mail *out* of our building will come from this IP (our client's spam filters won't let our mail through - reverse DNS problems).

I'm banging my head against my desk: this MUST be possible, or how would a company that has a single IP address be able to resolve web traffic? Can anyone help? Sorry if the questions doesn't make a lot of sense - I always find questions like this difficult to express!

**Update / Things I've tried**

- Ensure remote management is disabled (it's never been enabled anyway) [screen](http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/9590/screenshot20110415at103.png)
- Rebooted firewall
- Checked for firmware updates
- Tried adding DMZ WAN rule in place of a LAN WAN rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Turn off remote management or move it to a different port.</strike> Beat it over the head then offer it chocolate. Repeat cycle until it actually turns off remote management. Then complain to your vendor about the buggy firmware.

**Edit, new answer:** Remove all special "forwarding" style rules and put `1.1.1.9` in a DMZ zone so that all outside calls get routed to it instead.

**Edit, right answer:** Connect to the right device. (see comments)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but remote management is completely off.

Comment: @Rowan: Huh. Well that' dumb. It sounds like it's ignoring you. Please tell me you rebooted it :) See my edited answer for another idea.

Comment: Yep, rebooted, see comments in @iserko's answer

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what would the DMZ thing do? I'm not 100% sure what you mean, sorry!

Comment: DMZ (Acronym borrowed from the military meaning Demilitarized Zone) is a common configuration option on firewall and router appliances that allow you to expose one (or in advanced systems, more) computers on the "inside" of a protected network as if they were really on the outside. They still have full access to the other inside resources, but they themselves live outside the fortified walls and this are easy to run as servers interfacing with the outside world.

Comment: OK, I think I understand what that is now, but what will adding 1.1.1.2 to a DMZ zone do? Can you guess I'm not a *real* sysadmin? :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I write that address from memory, but the example from your post should have been `1.1.1.9`.

Comment: ah I see! give me a mo, cheers

Comment: OK, adding a DMZ WAN rule has *exactly* the same effect as adding a LAN WAN rule, the 123.123.123.102 just hangs

Comment: I looked up specs on that thing and it looks like it is known to over-promise and under-deliver. I see it actually has hardware DMZ ports. Did you try putting the mentioned dot-9 webserver into that port? Which WAN port are you using? You aren't using both WAN ports are you?

Comment: Nope, we're only using WAN 1, WAN 2 has no cable plugged in and nothing configured for it. I can't plug dot-9 into that at the moment (Boss won't be happy - mail will go down), but I have a webserver running on my personal machine so we'll try plugging me (my machine, not me personally) directly into the firewall. Keep you updated, thanks so much!

Comment: Ballsy balls! OK, we have two firewalls running in parallel, the new one on 1.1.1.2 and the old one on 1.1.1.3. When we changed 1.1.1.9 to my machine's IP (1.1.1.199) it just worked! Then we realised that 1.1.1.9 is connected to the internetz via 1.1.1.3, but my machine's connected via 1.1.1.2, doh! moving my machine to use 1.1.1.3 causes the same hanging behaviour... I feel like such a noob!

Comment: Um. Ya. So forwarding to a device inside the network that is talking to the outside world via a different router will definitively screw up your network!

Comment: Thanks for being my [Rubber Duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)! I think you probably contributed most, although the real answer is: "Rowan, you shouldn't be configuring a firewall, stick to the websites..."

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 reasons why the router admin page would show up on port 80.

- you connected the WAN (your ISP's connection) to a LAN port (probably unlikely since you would have had to set the public IP on the LAN interface)
- the remote management port is set to port 80 (check under Administration -> Remote Management)

Comment: Point one may be the issue, point two I've already tried - remote management is completely disabled! As you may have guessed, I'm not *really* a 'server admin', I've been tasked with this because 'web developer' is the closest we've got... Could you explain point one a little more? I'm not 100% sure how I'd actually go about checking/solving that.. Thanks :)

Comment: Well first of all check where the WAN cable (the one from the ISP's device) is plugged in to. As far as I can see it should be plugged into one of the WAN ports on the left side. Can you check that?

Comment: Yep, that's plugged into WAN1 so not a problem

Comment: OK, that means that your Internet connection is good. You can access the internet through it normally, right?

Comment: Yep, there's no problem connecting to the internet at all

Comment: Next thing I'd try doing is just check what port the Remote Administration is set to. If its set to port 80 ... just change it to 8080 and apply settings. And if possible reboot the router afterwards. Just in case turning it off didn't work.

Comment: Can you telnet to the device and view comprehensive logs to paste here by chance?

Comment: Remote management is off, and the port setting is 8080 currently - here's a screenshot of the Administration/Remote Managment page: http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/9590/screenshot20110415at103.png

Comment: Did you reboot the router?

Comment: Just rebooted, still having the same problems, will look into logs

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if the firewall's firmware is buggy. Have you checked to see whether you're running the latest version of the firmware?

You may want to try enabling remote management, restricting the access to some bogus IP address (127.0.0.1 should do just fine), and changing the port number. At that point, it may be possible to install the inbound forwarding rules you want.

Note that you can have reverse DNS entries that point 123.123.123.102 to example.com so that your mail works, while still having forward DNS entries that point example.com and www.example.com somewhere else...but I would endeavor to avoid this situation if possible.

Comment: Firmware is completely up-to-date, I'll try setting remote management with a bogus IP temporarily

Comment: That had no effect I'm afraid :(